# Problems with Python 3 Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

1. The output that player xyz has won is being printed after playing one more chance after winning.
2. Even when player 2 wins, the output prints player 1 has won
   I've experimented a little and tried to solve it by myself but no luck until now.
   Also, if you have any suggestions to make the code more efficient or more presentable please drop it below.
   My code:

```py
def printrow(r1,r2,r3):
    print(r1)
    print(r2)
    print(r3)
def empty(inp):
    if inp!='-':
        print("Please enter a position which is empty")
    else:
        return 'valid'
def user1(inp):
    if inp not in range(1,10):
        print("Please enter a number in the range of 1 to 9")
    else:
        if inp==1:
            if empty(row1[0])=='valid':
                row1[0]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
        elif inp==2:
            if empty(row1[1])=='valid':
                row1[1]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
        elif inp==3:
            if empty(row1[2])=='valid':
                row1[2]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
        elif inp==4:
            if empty(row2[0])=='valid':
                row2[0]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
        elif inp==5:
            if empty(row2[1])=='valid':
                row2[1]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
        elif inp==6:
            if empty(row2[2])=='valid':
                row2[2]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
        elif inp==7:
            if empty(row3[0])=='valid':
                row3[0]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
        elif inp==8:
            if empty(row3[1])=='valid':
                row3[1]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
        elif inp==9:
            if empty(row3[2])=='valid':
                row3[2]='X'
                printrow(row1,row2,row3)
def user2(inp):
        if inp not in range(1, 10):
            print("Please enter a number in the range of 1 to 9")
        else:
            if inp == 1:
                if empty(row1[0]) == 'valid':
                    row1[0] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
            elif inp == 2:
                if empty(row1[1]) == 'valid':
                    row1[1] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
            elif inp == 3:
                if empty(row1[2]) == 'valid':
                    row1[2] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
            elif inp == 4:
                if empty(row2[0]) == 'valid':
                    row2[0] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
            elif inp == 5:
                if empty(row2[1]) == 'valid':
                    row2[1] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
            elif inp == 6:
                if empty(row2[2]) == 'valid':
                    row2[2] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
            elif inp == 7:
                if empty(row3[0]) == 'valid':
                    row3[0] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
            elif inp == 8:
                if empty(row3[1]) == 'valid':
                    row3[1] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
            elif inp == 9:
                if empty(row3[2]) == 'valid':
                    row3[2] = '0'
                    printrow(row1,row2,row3)
def check(r1,r2,r3):
            if r1[0] == 'X' and r1[1] == 'X' and r1[2] == 'X':
                return "Congratulations Player 1! You won."
            elif r1[0] == 'X' and r2[0] == 'X' and r3[0] == 'X':
                return "Congratulations Player 1! You won."
            elif r1[0] == 'X' and r2[1] == 'X' and r3[2] == 'X':
                return "Congratulations Player 1! You won."
            elif r1[1] == 'X' and r2[1] == 'X' and r3[1] == 'X':
                return "Congratulations Player 1! You won."
            elif r1[2] == 'X' and r2[2] == 'X' and r3[2] == 'X':
                return "Congratulations Player 1! You won."
            elif r1[2] == 'X' and r2[1] == 'X' and r3[0] == 'X':
                return "Congratulations Player 1! You won."
            elif r2[0] == 'X' and r2[1] == 'X' and r2[2] == 'X':
                return "Congratulations Player 1! You won."
            elif r3[0] == 'X' and r3[1] == 'X' and r3[2] == 'X':
                return "Congratulations Player 1! You won."
            elif r1[0] == '0' and r1[1] == '0' and r1[2] == '0':
                return "Congratulations Player 2! You won."
            elif r1[0] == '0' and r2[0] == '0' and r3[0] == '0':
                return "Congratulations Player 2! You won."
            elif r1[0] == '0' and r2[1] == '0' and r3[2] == '0':
                return "Congratulations Player 2! You won."
            elif r1[1] == '0' and r2[1] == '0' and r3[1] == '0':
                return "Congratulations Player 2! You won."
            elif r1[2] == '0' and r2[2] == '0' and r3[2] == '0':
                return "Congratulations Player 2! You won."
            elif r1[2] == '0' and r2[1] == '0' and r3[0] == '0':
                return "Congratulations Player 2! You won."
            elif r2[0] == '0' and r2[1] == '0' and r2[2] == '0':
                return "Congratulations Player 2! You won."
            elif r3[0] == '0' and r3[1] == '0' and r3[2] == '0':
                return "Congratulations Player 2! You won."
print("[1,2,3]\n[4,5,6]\n[7,8,9]")
count=0; winner=False
row1=['-','-','-']
row2= ['-','-','-']
row3=['-','-','-']
print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe")
print("Player 1 will be X and will start the game, and player 2 will be 0 and play second.")
while winner == False:
    if count<9:
        count+=1
        if type(check(row1,row2,row3))==str:
            print(check(row1,row2,row3))
        else:
            inp=int(input("Player 1:  Where do you want to insert the next X?    "))
            user1(inp)
            inp=int(input("Player 2:  Where do you want to insert the next 0?    "))
            user2(inp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem #1: the loop doesn't stop after you call `check()`, so the game will continue. You could call `break` to exit from the loop and end the game.

Problem #2: I tried running your code and it said that player 2 won.

```
Player 1:  Where do you want to insert the next X?    4
['X', 'X', '0']
['X', '0', '-']
['-', '-', '-']
Player 2:  Where do you want to insert the next 0?    7
['X', 'X', '0']
['X', '0', '-']
['0', '-', '-']
Congratulations Player 2! You won.
Congratulations Player 2! You won.
Congratulations Player 2! You won.
Congratulations Player 2! You won.
Congratulations Player 2! You won.
Congratulations Player 2! You won.
```

General feedback: it's a worrying sign when code is repeated a bunch of times. It takes more effort to write, it's more difficult to understand, and it's easier for bugs to slip in. A good rule of thumb is that when you find yourself copy/pasting code a bunch of times, use a loop instead! In this case, you probably don't need all those `if`s. And you probably don't need to duplicate the code for player 1 & player 2 - can you think of a way to reuse the same code for both of them? Maybe a function?